# OpenGL Drawing 2 vectors with a given angle between them

Tags: c++, opengl, vector-graphics, radians

I'm trying to draw in OpenGL 2 vectors with a given angle (in radians) between them, something like this:

[image]

I managed to draw the vectors but I'm not sure how to place them at the specific angle:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);  // Vx
glColor4f(1, .5, 0, 1);
glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(0, vectorYRScalingValue, 0);  // vectorYRScalingValue is 5.0
glEnd();
glBegin(GL_LINES);  // Vy
glColor4f(1, .5, 0, 1);
glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
glVertex3f(0, vectorYRScalingValue, 0);
glEnd();
```

Comment: Start your web browser, open your favorite search engine and search for, e.g. _"2d vector rotation"_. I've got as first entry https://matthew-brett.github.io/teaching/rotation_2d.html and the second one was https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix and it took me about 30 seconds (more or less). Evidently you have no issues to present them on screen (unless you don't know what the parameters of `glVertex3f` stand for).

Answer (score 0):

If β is the angle to be rotated in radians.

We rotate this vector anticlockwise around the origin.

```
float c = cos(β);
float s = sin(β);

NewX = x * c - y * s; 
NewY = x * s + y * c;
```